# How does HIV infect people?

Tags: sex, hiv

If a person had sex with multiple people and none of them were infected with HIV,
would it cause the generation of HIV in his/her body?

Does sex with multiple partners lead to the generation of HIV?

As heard and read about HIV many people say "Only if sex partner is infected with it,  you are going to get it". But the question is, how is that partner infected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is really the cause of HIV?](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4901/what-is-really-the-cause-of-hiv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only get HIV from someone or something already infected. This includes humans, needles, breast milk, etc. HIV virus must come in contact with a damaged or open tissue.

[CDC.gov](http://www.cdc.gov/hiv/basics/transmission.html)

> You can get or transmit HIV only through specific activities. Most
>   commonly, people get or transmit HIV through sexual behaviors and
>   needle or syringe use.

You must have the infection to transmit it. Multiple partners increase risk, but only transmit if one partner already has infection.

How does a person get HIV? From someone or something already infected. If we go back to the first person infected then:

[AIDS institute](http://www.theaidsinstitute.org/education/aids-101/where-did-hiv-come-0)

> They believe that the chimpanzee version of the immunodeficiency virus
>   (called simian immunodeficiency virus or SIV) most likely was
>   transmitted to humans and mutated into HIV when humans hunted these
>   chimpanzees for meat and came into contact with their infected blood.

Comment: You should specify that HIV is transmitted through fluids.

You should also clarify that this is a retro-viral infection. HIV changes the genome. Since it "splices" itself into your genes your body begins to produce the virus naturally.

Comment: @FrankyG Sure and thanks for the heads up.  I will add it as soon I get some time.